# what is the meaning of some random number at end of the path?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using windows 10. When I open powershell inside any project, I am getting some random number at the end of the path like

```
 [bash ≡ +5 ~3 -0 !]
```

[image]

- Could any one shed some lights on what it is ?
- How do I disable or remove it?

Comment: Google for "posh-git". It is a feature of that, that shows you your "Git" stats in the prompt (files changed, etc.).

Comment: Thank you.. I was looking for the word to search..

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Posh-Git. It basically summarizes the `git status` of the current repo if your location path is inside of one.

[Here is the **README.md** for Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#git-status-summary-information), linked specifically to the bit which explains the git status summary.

If you're working with Git I highly recommend leaving it enabled. But, if it's not your flavor, you can remove it by opening `$profile` in a text editor:

```
notepad $profile
```

and either edit out the "git-status" reference from your `global:prompt` function or remove `global:prompt` entirely in the case you aren't customizing the prompt in any other way.